# Which Screen Scraper should I use for Dynamic Webpages?

Tags: .net, mysql, database, ajax

I m looking to develop a program, which collects data from 6 different websites and displaying information which changes dynamically.

In order to develop such program I require a screen scraper utility which is able to extract data simultaneously from 6 different WebPages on which the data changes at a very high frequency.

See the link below to get an idea of the type and the dynamic manner in which the data is displayed.

http://www.igmarkets.com.au/pricestream/outside/getMarketList?webSiteId=zam&businessArea=F&locale=en_ZA&firstTime=true&skin=igindex

The info is displayed somewhat differently on the 6 webpages, but the concept is very similar.

Can anyone please advise what is the correct utility software which is ideal for such purpose.

Many thanks

Comment: But you have the permission to scrape those pages, have you?

Comment: Not sure - if I do ? most prbably not... is that a problem?

Comment: @Nitzan it most likely is. That data is somebody else's property and must usually be neither scraped nor copied, see their [T&C](http://www.igmarkets.com.au/cfd/terms-and-conditions.html)

Comment: Copyright is copyright. Unless you have permission, or it's pre-packaged in some kind of syndicated format (which it clearly isn't), then no fair redistributing it.

Comment: @Daniel: You forgot <yodavoice>...</yodavoice>  ;>

Comment: @Nitzan: Btw I get a permission denied when accessing the example link.

Answer (score 0):

Ethically screen scraping can be a dubious practice - but there are legitimate uses.  Search Engines do a kind of scrape to get their results, as an example.

Some sites will block utilities that make too many requests - which is a good reason to ask permission if you are going to make many requests - as it may otherwise look like a [DoS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and the site may take action against you.

All that aside if you have a legitimate use to read the contents of a page (so that you can process it in some way) the code is fairly trivial.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.71).aspx)

In C#:

```
// Initialize the WebRequest.
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");

// Return the response. 
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

// Code to use the WebResponse goes here.

// Close the response to free resources.
myResponse.Close();
```